# Why are my files in /var/lock and where did they just go?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I am hosting a website on Debian 5.0 & Apache2. Today one of my websites was down, Apache said it couldn't find the directory.

I located the files and the whole site once in /var/www/site was now /var/lock/site. All the files were present.

I was confused, but figured I'd just move it back.

mv /var/lock/site /var/www

All looked fine... Except that only the directories moved and the files appear to be lost!

I am working on restoring from backups but I would really love to know what happened and where my files went (the backups are a few days old).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, that sounds like it wasn't triggered by any system mechanism. You should read through the logs and try to spot anything suspicious. Without any logs, the diagnosis is impossible.